# getting error while testing two conditions in if statement Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
function IsValidMacAddress($checkvariable)
{
  Write-Output "checking mac"
  if(($checkvariable -match '^[0-9a-fA-F]+$') -and ($checkvariable.length -eq 12)) 
  {
    Write-Output "valid mac"
    return 1
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Output "not found"
    return 0
  }
}
```

**this always returns not found**

Answer (score 0):

only slightly different, but try this

```
function IsValidMacAddress ([string]$checkvariable) {
    $checkvariable = $checkvariable -replace '-|:'
    Write-Host "checking mac $checkvariable"
    if ($checkvariable -match '^[0-9a-f]{12}$') {
        Write-Host "$checkvariable is valid mac"
        return 1
    } else {
        Write-Host "$checkvariable is not valid mac"
        return 0
    }
}

IsValidMacAddress de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe
IsValidMacAddress de-ad-be-ef-ca-fe
IsValidMacAddress dead-beef-cafe
IsValidMacAddress deadbeefcafe
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I should essentially, but not using colons in mac address here so for me it worked like this, function IsValidMacAddress($checkvariable)
{
  if(([String]$checkvariable).length -eq 12 -And $checkvariable -match '^[0-9a-fA-F]+$') 
  {
    Write-Output "valid mac"
    return 1
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Output "not found"
    return 0
  }
}